# Evaluate a ruby or javascript script string from within an android program

Tags: android, scripting

Is it possible to evaluate a string expression script from within an android app? Using either ruby, javascript or perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at the following project, it seems to do what you're after:

> #### Android Scripting
>
> http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/